# Managing Locks on RG, auto remove locks

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure, azure-resource-group

I have such a module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.50.0"
    }
  }
}

module "azure_general" {
  source          = "../azure_general"
  environment     = var.environment
  organization    = var.organization
  location        = var.location
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = module.azure_general.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = module.azure_general.tenant_id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.project_name}-rg-${module.azure_general.location_alias}-${var.environment}"
  location = module.azure_general.location
  tags = merge(
    {
      projectName  = var.project_name
      teamName     = var.team_name
      organization = var.organization
      environment  = var.environment
      availability = module.azure_general.availability
      deployType   = "Terraform"
    },
    var.tags
  )
}

resource "azurerm_management_lock" "rg_lock" {
  name       = "LockDelete"
  scope      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  lock_level = "CanNotDelete"
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "resource_group_subscription" {
  value = module.azure_general.subscription_id
}

output "resource_group_id" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
}

output "resource_group_location" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
}
```

In each Resource Group, which was created with the modulus also created a lock on RG. But now to change something in the Resource Group I have to remove the lock first. But… when I remove the lock manually, it is the first to be put on the next terraform apply, and the rest does not change.

What I mean is that, for example, I have two virtual machines in the resource group, then I want to change their system or Size using terraform, then first terraform must remove them, but it can’t because lock blocks it.

How can I automate this? Or write some modul? I wouldn’t want to do something manually either.

I simply removed the lock each time before deleting the machine. Faster than terraform apply

Comment: Can you please provide more info about   **source = "../azure_general"** file mentioned here

Comment: organizations = {
    (org_name)= {
      organization_shortname = "sh"
      environments = {
        test = {
          subscription_id       = "id"
          location              = "northeurope"
          availability          = "8x5"
          environment_shortname = "t"
        }

etc. 
It is just a module that contains organizations, subscriptions, and environments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply here two tricks.

1. Force management lock to be recreated:

```
resource "null_resource" "always_run" {
  triggers = {
    timestamp = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "rg_lock" {
  name       = "LockDelete"
  scope      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  lock_level = "CanNotDelete"

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      null_resource.always_run
    ]
  }
}
```

It requires terraform in version 1.2.0

2. Create proper dependencies between resources, so management lock would be created at the end of process by adding `depends_on`

```
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "rg_lock" {
  name       = "LockDelete"
  scope      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  lock_level = "CanNotDelete"

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      null_resource.always_run
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [module.azure_general, azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}
```

Comment: Thansk, i will try it tommorow!

Comment: Hello, I tested it, it's actually a cool method but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. We have workflow that run to check whether the state file matches the infrastructure. And then the result will be that there is a null resource in the state file, but not in the infrastructure :/